# Angular 2 - How to read the file from the given URL using FileReader in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, jenkins, filereader

I have jenkins build which contains Build Artifacts. The Artifact contains a text file. I want to access this file and read the file. This file contains some version tag.I want to display this file content in the Angular 2 typescript application.

> Jenkins REST API to access the artifact file -
>   http://localhost:8080/job/myjobname/job/develop/59/artifact/build/docker/myFileName.txt

As soon as I hit this URL in the browser it will download the text file.

I want to only read the file from this given URL in my Angular 2 typescript application. How can I read this file from URL using FileReader? Is there any other better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileReader` can only read Blobs ([`Blob`](https://devdocs.io/dom/blob) and the subclassed [`File`](https://devdocs.io/dom/file) object). To read an *URL* you can use either the new [`fetch()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/fetch_api/using_fetch) or the classic [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/xmlhttprequest). You can of course request the content as a blob and then read it via `FileReader`, but if the content is text it makes more sense to read it directly as such.

There are typically [CORS restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) you will have to deal with as well though, unless the URL points to somewhere within the same origin as your calling page.

Comment: Thanks :) Tried with XMLHttpRequest() and I get this error No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @user1731770 that's why I mention CORS restriction in the answer.  Just read the requirements in the link - basically, you need to setup the server to allow cross-origin requests.